# TypeError: keywords must be strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am attempting to transition this program

https://github.com/adambeagle/JeoparPy

from 2.7 to 3.7. I have run the program with 2.7 and it works.

I have already made modifications for xrange -> range and basestring -> str. I have also altered the import paths.

Here is the error I get when executing start.py:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "start.py", line 64, in <module>
    main(*flags)
  File "D:\Users\Michael\IdeaProjects\JeoparPy\jeoparpy\main.py", line 55, in main
    uicontroller = Controller(screen, gameData, FPS_LIMIT)
  File "D:\Users\Michael\IdeaProjects\JeoparPy\jeoparpy\ui\controller.py", line 57, in __init__
    self.audioplayer = JeopAudioPlayer()
  File "D:\Users\Michael\IdeaProjects\JeoparPy\jeoparpy\ui\audioplayer.py", line 111, in __init__
    super().__init__(dict(SOUNDS, **reads))
TypeError: keywords must be strings
```

The error 'keywords must be strings' refers to this class:

I don't understand which variable is not a string. 'pos' seems to be a local variable that stands for position.

```
class JeopAudioPlayer(AudioPlayer):
    """An AudioPlayer with JeoparPy sounds initialized."""
    def __init__(self):
        reads = {}
        for pos, path in CLUE_READS.items():
            key = pos + ('cr', )
            reads[key] = path

        super().__init__(dict(SOUNDS, **reads))
```

Here is the SOUNDS dictionary from resmaps:

```
SOUNDS = {(0, 4) : _sndPath + 'sample_music.ogg',
          (1, 4) : _sndPath + 'sample_music.ogg',
          (2, 4) : _sndPath + 'sample_music.ogg',
          (3, 4) : _sndPath + 'sample_music.ogg',
          (4, 4) : _sndPath + 'sample_music.ogg',
          }
```

The CLUE_READS dictionary is very similar:

```
CLUE_READS = {(0, 2) : _cluesPath + 'sample_read.ogg',
              (1, 2) : _cluesPath + 'sample_read.ogg',
              (2, 2) : _cluesPath + 'sample_read.ogg',
              (3, 2) : _cluesPath + 'sample_read.ogg',
              (4, 2) : _cluesPath + 'sample_read.ogg',
              }
```

This is how the paths are defined:

```
from jeoparpy.constants import ROOT_PATH

_fontPath = path.join(ROOT_PATH, 'res', 'fonts', '')
_imgPath = path.join(ROOT_PATH, 'res', 'images', '')
_sndPath = path.join(ROOT_PATH, 'res', 'sounds', '')
_cluesPath = path.join(ROOT_PATH, 'res', 'sounds', 'clues', '')
```

And just in case, here is the ROOT_PATH:

```
ROOT_PATH = path.abspath(path.join(path.dirname(__file__), pardir))
```

Comment: `key = pos + ('cr', )` what is `pos`

Comment: What does the `CLUE_READS` (dictionary) look like?

Comment: @SuperStew updated the post

Answer (score 2):

`SOUNDS` and `reads` are both already dictionaries. There's no point passing them as keyword arguments to a `dict` constructor; just update one from the other. Since `reads` was created entirely within the method, it's safe to update it directly with the contents of `SOUNDS`.

```
reads.update(SOUNDS)
super().__init__(reads)
```

Comment: This allows the program to run (yay!) but removes the CLUE_READS association of the method. When the clue is opened there is supposed to be an audio file that plays that reads the clue.